# release() was not declared c++

Tags: c++

I am working on one project
I created function where I used dynamic memory and then trie to relese it in function itself.
On compiling it gives error as release()was not declared.

> int *cumprod = (int *)malloc(neighbood_dim * sizeof(*cumprod));
>
> release(cumprod);

This is inside function.

What is the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `free()` not `release()`.

Alternatively, since you're using C++, you could instead use `new/delete`, like so:

```
int *cumprod = new int[neighbood_dim];

delete[] cumprod;
```

Comment: Thanx for answering. What is the difference among both?

Comment: `release()` isn't an actual function you can use.

Comment: Your `std::unique_ptr` example allocates a single int with value `neighbood_dim`, not an array with that many elements. You can manage a dynamic array with `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`, but the superior tool for that is `std::vector<int>`.